# Max-width Overridden on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I'm not seeing why `max-width: 400px` is forcing the image to be 400px on small screens for the following site:

On https://compucademy.net/hypothesis-testing-with-python/

Can anyone explain please, and maybe give me an appropriate @media rule to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It isn't being overridden, it's rendered at 400px...

Comment: But when I uncheck the rule, it reverts to the right size. Shouldn't max-width allow for smaller if needed?

Comment: @BenM My wording was off. It's being forced to 400px, which is not what I expect max-width to do.

Comment: Not if the intrinsic size is larger than `400px`. If you uncheck `max-width: 400px`, `max-width: 66%` will be used by the browser, which in this instance will be less than 400px.

Comment: @BenM So what would I put in a media query for small screens? `unset` maybe?

Comment: What's wrong with `max-width: 100%` across the board?

Comment: @BenM Because the images on my site aren't great and I don't want them displayed full size.

Comment: So set `max-width: 100%` on smaller devices, then.

Comment: @BenM Perfect. Thanks. I didn't know that max-width couldn't shrink past intrinsic size.

Answer (score -1):

Width is being overridden, for mobile specific you can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.... CSS goes here
}
```

You can also use the "min-width" if its mobile priority application/website.
Hope this help.

Comment: I know about media queries, but I don't know what the rule should be, as I would expect max-width to shrink on smaller screens... I would expect min-width to produce the current behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It gave me half the answer...